# How to get filenames and md5sum from google bucket in csv format with gsutil ls

Tags: linux, bash, google-cloud-storage, gsutil

I am trying to to get all files from google cloud storage with md5sum and all as csv.

**Condition**: run it from bash and use only linux commands

**When I run this:**

```
gsutil ls -L -r gs://some-bucket/subfolder/**
```

**It returns yaml as a stream:**

```
gs://sombucket/subfolder/filename1.jpg:
    Creation time:          Wed, 09 Feb 2022 16:44:55 GMT
    Update time:            Wed, 09 Feb 2022 16:44:55 GMT
    Storage class:          STANDARD
    Content-Length:         11466
    Content-Type:           image/jpeg
    Hash (crc32c):          waea9g==
    Hash (md5):             HGTN2JFXASB0bfSH14hJGQ==
    ETag:                   CLq0mO2I8/UCEAE=
    Generation:             1644425095027258
    Metageneration:         1
    ACL:                    []
```

**What I'd like to see is this:**

```
gs://sombucket/subfolder/filename1.jpg,HGTN2JFXASB0bfSH14hJGQ==
... (and other files)
```

Comment: I expected simple gsutil flag 'gsutil ls --csv' or something, but I cannot see it? Maybe I missed it? :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**With a docker:**

```
docker run --name gcloud-gsutil-vladimir --rm --volumes-from gcloud-config -i google/cloud-sdk:latest gsutil ls -L -r gs://some-bucket/subfolder/**|egrep "gs.*@@.*jpg|md5.*"|tr -d '\n'|tr -s '=' '\n'| sed 's/Hash (md5)://'|sed 's/$/==/g'|sed 's/: //'|tr -s ' ' ','
```

Or use gsutil directly if installed:

```
gsutil ls -L -r gs://some-bucket/subfolder/**|egrep "gs.*@@.*jpg|md5.*"|tr -d '\n'|tr -s '=' '\n'| sed 's/Hash (md5)://'|sed 's/$/==/g'|sed 's/: //'|tr -s ' ' ','
```

Steps:

1. Run `gsutil` and pipe it to `egrep` to get only lines with filename and md5sum
2. Remove all the new line characters from the stream with `tr -d '\n'`
3. Lean on md5sum ending '==' to replace it again with the newline (the one we need) with `tr -s '=' '\n'`
4. Optionally remove other things like "Hash (md5):"
5. Use sed to return removed "==" to the end of the line `sed 's/$/==/g'`
6. Remove ': ' (colon with space after ".jpg: ")
7. Finally replace all spaces with the comma with `tr -s ' ' ','`

This is one-liner that I've been looking for. It works but probably it could be achieved with less steps and less tools.

I know this can be achieved with python, perl and whatnot - but I would happy to see other "one-liner" approaches.